# Create a dynamic list with popup underneath each object (in vue)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I dont think Vue is neccesary because right now because most are done with javascript/css.

I am trying to create a list that looks like this:

```
   [A] [B]
   [C] [D]
```

and once an item is clicked, the info about that item is displayed undearneath like so: ( the arrow indicates which item was clicked.

```
   [A]    [B]        [A]    [B]
   [^ A-Info]        [C]    [D]
   [C]    [D]        [D-Info ^]
```

I am trying to make this happen by creating a list of objects each holding the header info and the details underneath. 
I am creating the elements in a v-for like this:

```
<template v-for item in items>
 <div class="header" @click="isVisible = true">
 <div class="details" v-show="isVisible">
</template>
```

But this will make it looks like this when clicked:

```
[A]
[^       ]
[B]    [C]
[D]
```

The reason to this is quite obvious, because that is the order they are in the dom object. My solution is the create two header objects and one details underneath them and populate that one with the info from the header objects that is clicked, but that seems like a too advanced solution. Is this possible to simply solve with css or something else?

Comment: Can you share the structure of the data that you are trying to populate this layout with? ie. `[ {label: 'Item A', details: 'Lorem ipsum yada yada'}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your data looks like, it's kind of hard to provide a complete solution. However, what you are describing sounds a lot like a tabbed layout, with possibly multiple rows of tabs. You can accomplish what you want using the `v-show` directive, only showing a details section if it matches your selected item. For example:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <template v-for="row in rows">
      <tr>
        <th
          v-for="item in row"
          v-text="item.label"
          :class="{ selected: item.id === selectedId }"
          @click="selectItem(item.id)"        
        ></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td      
          :colspan="row.length"      
          v-for="item in row"
          v-show="item.id === selectedId"
          v-html="item.details"
        ></td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selectedId: 1,
    rows: [
      [
        {
          id: 1,
          label: "Item A",
          details: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultricies vitae massa vel cursus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum finibus iaculis.'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          label: "Item B",
          details: 'Mauris placerat, est in finibus consectetur, ligula urna imperdiet velit, vel interdum lacus turpis a nisi. Etiam et neque sed dui maximus posuere.'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          id: 3,
          label: "Item C",
          details: 'Vivamus consectetur maximus diam tincidunt bibendum. Fusce quis euismod risus.'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          label: "Item D",
          details: 'Nam convallis diam sit amet purus lacinia, in euismod sem porttitor. Sed magna quam, consequat in aliquet ut, faucibus nec massa.'
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    selectItem(id) {
        this.selectedId = id;
    }
  }
})
```

**CSS**:

```
/* Styles */

table {
  padding: 20px;
}
th {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
th.selected {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
td {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

I've added a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/cn4egdxq/6/) for you to play around with.

Comment: that's basically how my data looks yes.
{title,
 ingress,
 imageUrl}

But it can be changed, it is not set in stone yet.

I will try your soution, tomorrow but it does look like what I want to do! Thank you, ill get back to you.

Comment: btw, would it be possible to make the rows dynamic with this without too much hassle? Like 1 row if the window with is 700 otherwise 2 rows?

Comment: Yeah, that's not too complicated. You'd just need to listen to the `window.resize` event.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I didnt use a table but instead just used divs (already had css for it so the table wasnt needed) but the idea with the nested for loops was great. Then I have a function to convert the input list into a list of list and each list represent a row like in your case.

I have the function here https://jsfiddle.net/c7sakomt/4/ what do you think of it?